# What is the compliant way to handle an sbrk() failure?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

How should I actually handle this? Note that in my code SBRK_FAIL is a symbolic constant for -1.
However, when sbrk(0) does not fail, it returns a pointer. I don't want to compare a pointer with an integer value. Can anyone recommend a better way to do this? Thanks.

```
p = sbrk(0);
if (p == SBRK_FAIL) {
    user_ptr = NULL;

}
```

Comment: In documentation it says "On error, (void *) -1 is returned, and errno is set to ENOMEM".

You should be able to safely compare return value with `(void*) -1` since pointers are integers.

Comment: Why would you use sbrk?

Comment: Thanks @thoron. And i'm using it because i'm implementing a memory allocator.

Comment: Modern memory allocators use mmap. sbrk is considered stupid.

Comment: Thats good information to know. What is the reason for that?

Comment: @thoron, pointers are _not_ integers (though the casted compare will work)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It might be accurate to say that, *in POSIX*, pointers are integers. You can at least always compare `(void*)` constants such as the error returns from sbrk and mmap.

Comment: @JaydenRivers One reason I know to prefer mmap over sbrk is that sbrk has to be contiguous in virtual memory. This is not so much of a problem in a program that uses no threads and is statically linked. But when using thread stacks and dynamic libraries, these are allocated randomly in virtual memory (because of ASLR) and your program's sbrk space may collide with another allocation. mmap on the other hand can allocate a block from anywhere there is room in the memory map.

Comment: I know that ptmalloc and tcmalloc use sbrk for smaller allocations and mmap for larger. Is that due to the same reasoning you have given?

Comment: Additional question: can -1 ever be interpreted in its unsigned form as a memory address, producing a segfault?